# Specifying row names when reading in a file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I have a `.txt` file that contains row names. However, R set the row names as the first column.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you used `read.table()` (or one of it's ilk, e.g. `read.csv()`) then the easy fix is to change the call to:

```
read.table(file = "foo.txt", row.names = 1, ....)
```

where `....` are the other arguments you needed/used. The `row.names` argument takes the column number of the data file from which to take the row names. It need not be the first column. See `?read.table` for details/info.

If you already have the data in R and can't be bothered to re-read it, or it came from another route, just set the `rownames` attribute and remove the first variable from the object (assuming `obj` is your object)

```
rownames(obj) <- obj[, 1]  ## set rownames
obj <- obj[, -1]           ## remove the first variable
```

Comment: You could also use column-based slicing (at least for matrix and dataframe). `rownames(obj) <- t(obj[1]) ##get row names from first column` `obj <- obj[-1] ## remove first column`

Comment: So, the integer for row.names is 1-indexed? The first column isn't called Column 0?

Comment: @Dr_Hope All vectors at the R level are 1-indexed, hence the first row is row 1 and the first column is column 1.

Answer (score 8):

See `?read.table`. Basically, when you use `read.table`, you specify a number indicating the column:

```
##Row names in the first column
read.table(filname.txt, row.names=1)
```