# reading file using fread with row and column names

Tags: r, csv, data.table

Using fread, how to read CSV file which contains row and column names. 
I tried following but it is not reading the row and column names properly.

The csv file looks like (where C1,C2,C3 are column names and r1, r2, r3 are row names)

```
input = ",C1,C2,C3
r1,A,B,C
r2,1,3,5
3,2,4,6"
```

I use function

```
require(data.table)
fread(input,header = TRUE)
```

which give

```
   r1 A B C
1: r2 1 3 5
2:  3 2 4 6
```

How can I properly read CSV using fread?

Comment: Have you tried adding `row.names = 1` when using `read.csv`? If not, you should take a look at `?read.csv`

Comment: @EricFail - Sorry I am new to R/data.table .. What does it has to do with read.csv?

Comment: have a look at [this SO tread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13271846/1305688).

Comment: I want to use fread because my data file is big and I do not want to use read.csv .

Comment: This seems to be fixed in [v1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)..

Answer (score 5):

You should submit a bug report.

Here is a work-around:

```
colnames <- strsplit(readLines(textConnection(input), n=1), ",")[[1]]
colnames[1] <- "rownames"
setnames(DT <- fread(input, skip=1, header=FALSE), colnames)
DT
#   rownames C1 C2 C3
#1:       r1  A  B  C
#2:       r2  1  3  5
#3:        3  2  4  6
```

As you should know, data.table doesn't support rownames.

Comment: @d.putto, it would be interesting to know if `fread()` is still faster in this case.

Comment: @EricFail Of course it is for a reasonably big file. You don't seem to know much about `fread` (and data.table).

Comment: I don't. I hadn't heard of `fread` until 50 minutes ago. I am here to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- data.frame(fread("example_file.csv",header = TRUE), row.names=1)
```

`fread()` is much faster than `read.csv()` for large files but `data.table` does not support row names. So either `data.frame()` or `matrix()` can be used if needed. I have used this method for a very large numeric data with column and row labels.

This question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425109/how-to-indicate-row-names-1-using-fread-in-data-table)