# Additional (unwanted) "X" in the header when importing .csv into R

Tags: r, import

I have this .csv document in my computer, and when I import it into R using the following code line:

```
dat <- read.table(file.choose(),sep=',', header=T)
```

I get:

```
    X COC EG EE AC LE ME SC
1  CE   3 22  0  0  4  3 50
2  AU  21  7  1  0  0  0 15
3  WA   4  0 10  0 12  0 21
4  HH   0 12  5  0  2  1  8
5  MH   0  2  0  2  2  0 26
6  HA   8  7  3  0  1  0  8
7  TY   0  0  0  0  0  0  1
8  PK   3  0  0  0  0  0  2
9  SR   0  1  0  0  0  0  1
10 FU   0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

This if fine, except for the "`X`" on top of the row names. There is no X on the original document:

```
,COC,EG,EE,AC,LE,ME,SC
CE,3,22,0,0,4,3,50
AU,21,7,1,0,0,0,15
WA,4,0,10,0,12,0,21
HH,0,12,5,0,2,1,8
MH,0,2,0,2,2,0,26
HA,8,7,3,0,1,0,8
TY,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
PK,3,0,0,0,0,0,2
SR,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
FU,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
```

How can I prevent this "`X`" from being automatically generated?

EDIT: After the comments below I tried `dat <- read.table(file.choose(),sep=',', header=T, check.names=F)`, and now the display if perfect.

HOWEVER, things are terribly wrong (as suggested in the comments). So if I do a

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  8 variables
```

When it should read `10 obs. of  7 variables`

I don't get it because if I refresh my memory with:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
```

... there is clearly an empty cell before the row names begin...

Comment: Add one in the original document? Column names cannot be empty.

Comment: If the column names start with numeric elements or missing, it will add `X`. If you don't need, `check.names=FALSE` is an option.  Though I am not sure what will happen in case of misssing column names.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the column name _can_ be empty, (use `check.names=FALSE`), but that makes the column very difficult to use in any meaningful way but perhaps `dat[[1]]`, and I wouldn't recommend doing that on a regular basis.

Comment: Please show the first lines of the actual file content. I suspect that your first column are actually rownames. That would mean that you should pass different parameters to `read.table`. Possibly it would be sufficient if you simply used `read.csv`.

Comment: See this post on SO about row names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271820/specifying-row-names-when-reading-in-a-file

Comment: @Roland I showed now the entire .csv file. When I tried `read.table()` a bizarre output:                        `V1
1  ,COC,EG,EE,AC,LE,ME,SC
2      CE,3,22,0,0,4,3,50`

Answer (score 0):

The credit goes to @Richard Erickson (see comments). Thanks to everybody else. I'm posting here to facilitate future searches for the same issue:

`read.table(file.choose(), row.names = 1, header=T, sep=",")`

```
   COC EG EE AC LE ME SC
CE   3 22  0  0  4  3 50
AU  21  7  1  0  0  0 15
WA   4  0 10  0 12  0 21
HH   0 12  5  0  2  1  8
MH   0  2  0  2  2  0 26
HA   8  7  3  0  1  0  8
TY   0  0  0  0  0  0  1
PK   3  0  0  0  0  0  2
SR   0  1  0  0  0  0  1
FU   0  0  0  0  0  0  2
```

And...

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ COC: int  3 21 4 0 0 8 0 3 0 0
 $ EG : int  22 7 0 12 2 7 0 0 1 0
 $ EE : int  0 1 10 5 0 3 0 0 0 0
 $ AC : int  0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0
 $ LE : int  4 0 12 2 2 1 0 0 0 0
 $ ME : int  3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 $ SC : int  50 15 21 8 26 8 1 2 1 2
```

So I guess that the issue wasn't the columns, but rather the row names that needed to be specified.